# How to evaluate this multiple Integral? Just making a different title.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, analysis, definite-integrals

$\iiint_{\Omega}x^{a}y^{b}z^{c}dxdydz$

$\Omega=\{(x,y,z)\in R^{3} | x+y+z \leq 1, x\geq 0, y\geq 0, z\geq 0\}$

I fed this to Wolfram Mathematica and the answer is:

${\Gamma(a+1)\Gamma(b+1)\Gamma(c+1)\over\Gamma(4+a+b+c)}$

Some freshman asked me for help and he beat me with this. The answer is beautiful yet the solution is unclear. Wonder what kind of change of variables will solve it. The Gamma function in the denominator is particularly baffling.

Comment: Words like "urgent" are not well-recieved here. For the integral: try the two-dimensional case (which is seen in the book Inside Interesting Integrals).

Comment: If you've seen the answer to the analogous question in two dimensions (look for the beta integral), then the Gamma in the denominator is not surprising.

Comment: "Just making a different title" is not a great improvement...

Answer (score 1):

I came up with a solution.

The denominator is actually illuminating.

$\ \ \ \ \iiint x^ay^bz^c\times\Gamma(4+a+b+c)\\=\iiint x^ay^bz^cdxdydz\int_{0}^{\infty}\alpha^{3+a+b+c}e^{-\alpha}d\alpha$

Making change of variables:

$\alpha=s_1+s_2+s_3+s_4, x={s_1\over\alpha}, y={s_2\over\alpha},z={s_3\over\alpha}$

After some algebra, the Jacobian is ${1\over\alpha^3}$:

$=\iiiint{s_1^as_2^bs_3^c\over\alpha^{a+b+c}}{ds_1ds_2ds_3ds_4\over\alpha^3}e^{-\alpha}\alpha^{3+a+b+c}$

The new domain of integration is $s_i\in [0,\infty)\ (i=1,2,3,4)$

$=\iiiint s_1^as_2^bs_3^ce^{-s_1-s_2-s_3-s_4}ds_1ds_2ds_3ds_4\\=\Gamma(a+1)\Gamma(b+1)\Gamma(c+1)$

Thus we proved mathematica's answer.

Comment: Well done. [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_distribution#Random_variate_generation) puts your solution in a well-known statistical context that may be of interest.

Comment: @J.G. Thanks for your supplement!

Comment: This is the Dirichlet integral applied to $(a+1,b+1,c+1,1).$